# java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type ARRAY

Tags: oracle, pyspark

I have an Oracle table with 5 columns, one of them being of the following type:

```
TYPE "C_ARRAY" IS VARRAY (500) OF c_my_type
```

My problem is that I am trying to read said table with PySpark 3.1.1 and I keep getting the following error that I don't really know how to fix:

```
An error occurred while calling o77.jdbc.: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type ARRAY
```

I tried indicating the table schema specifying the type of the problematic column as STRUCT or STRING, but haven't been lucky with it.

To be able to read from Oracle from Spark I am using the following jar from the 21.9 version (which if I am not mistaken is the latest), which can be downloaded [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html): ojdbc8-full.tar.gz